# Show that $E[x]=\int_0^\infty(1-F_X(x))dx$

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions

Show that $E[x]=\int_0^\infty(1-F_X(x))dx$
The solution is as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty P(X>x)dx &=\int_0^\infty \int_x^\infty f_X(y)dydx\\
&=\int_0^\infty  \int_0^y dxf_X(y)dy\\
&=\int_0^\infty yf_X(y)dy\\
&=E[X]
\end{align}$$

I don't understand step 3 in the solution, specifically while the limit of integration changed from $\infty$ to $y$.

Comment: You're missing something, perhaps that $X$ is nonnegative.

Comment: yes, its nonnegative. How does this help? @ Zachary Selk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the indicator function

$$1_{(y \geqslant x)}= \begin{cases}1, \,\,y \geqslant x \\ 0, \,\, y < x \end{cases},$$

we have

$$\int_0^\infty \left(\int_x^\infty f_X(y)dy\right)dx = \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty f_X(y)1_{(y \geqslant x)}dy\right)dx. $$

Since the integrand is non-negative, we can apply Tonelli's theorem to switch the order of integration and obtain

$$\int_0^\infty \left(\int_x^\infty f_X(y)dy\right)dx = \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^\infty f_X(y)1_{(y \geqslant x)}dx\right)dy \\ =  \int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^y f_X(y)dx\right)dy $$